# PHP V8Js on shared servers

Tags: php, html, node.js, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to build a MPA using Laravel 5.6 and Vue.js. What I basically want to do is pass in components to the blade templates. I've been doing a lot of research and I [read](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/non-node.html) I need PHP V8Js. I was wondering if this would work if I were to run my website on a shared server. PHP V8Js needs to be installed locally, so how would I make it work on a real server?

Comment: You're not going to find shared servers that have V8JS. You will need to roll your own server. However, I must ask, why do you *need* to do server-side rendering? You can just hide things with a loader so you don't see a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). Server side rendering introduces far more challenges than you would imagine and furthermore, is probably overkill for what you want.

Comment: What is a loader?

Comment: A *loader* in this context is [something like this](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)

Comment: OOOHHH NICE!!!!  Thank you!!!!! Would you use this specific loader or do you have any other suggestions? I'm still learning, so I'm sorry if I'm asking a lot of questions.

Comment: Also, do you think it is bad practice to use Vuejs without using a pre-renderer?

Comment: You can use any page loader that you want. Regarding pre-rendering, there's many strategies for that and it's a super generic question. I'd look into what other people are doing and do some more reading.